# Voting system quirks

Tags: support

So I asked a question on Stack Overflow, and it seemed like my accepted answer had the least down votes. All the other answers which offered pretty much the same solution had more down votes. Is this a bug in the voting system, or is it just that users don't downvote accepted answers as much?

*EDIT:* My accepted answer had ZERO downvotes.

Comment: Which answer are you referring to? We can fix this right now! j/k. Do mind posting the link, so that we can find out why? Maybe the answer contained information useful to others.

Comment: I believe the question this refers to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398787/javascript-shorthand-for-getelementbyid

Comment: @jzd That is correct.

Comment: I count four other answers without downvotes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will down vote an accepted answer if it is wrong.  But an accepted answer is a strong indication that it is correct, so I will think twice before I do.

Many of the other answers did not have down votes.  I don't think there is any bug in the system.

Comment: Good point. And people do tend to upvote the first answer they see, the accepted one :)

Comment: Although I downvoted an accepted answer once.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't attribute it to a bug in the system.

It's likely that the downvotes are indicitative of more human factors than cold-hard logical ones. For instance:

- Some people have taken umbrage with the usage of `$` fearing it may conflict with jQuery's `$`
- Some people may feel that the answer is similar enough to be considered as extra 'noise' and unscrupulous point-grabbing on behalf of the answerers (not my opinion, I hasten to add).
- It would be that those with the smaller reputation are also more prone to downvotes, as some will inherently trust a large number more.